# How to force Postgres using index?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, postgis

I have the following query that find all `id` inside`POLYGON(({points}))`

```
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE ST_DWithin('POLYGON(({points}))', ST_Point(latitude, longitude), 0);
```

The query is slow because it doesn't use `(latitude, longitude)` index and must compute the formula for every possible pair of points.

How can I change my query to force Postgres to use `(latitude, longitude)` index (I need to change the query because I cannot add some other index)?

I have the following index:

```
"index_latitude_longitude" btree (latitude, longitude)
```

latitude, longitude has `double precision` type

I think that Postgres will use the index if we add something like: `latitude <= ... and longitude <= ...`, how can we do this?

Comment: Could you please provide your DDL for table and index creation ?

Comment: @Arkhena updated question

Comment: I cannot add any other index or change something because I don't have any write permission to the db

Comment: Hi @ipetr, we supposing (by use of `ST_DWithin`) that you using PostGIS extension of PostgreSQL (please add a "postgis" tag)... So, you not need to do the latitude/longitude analysis, PostGIS will do for you.  I suggest also to review [`ST_DWithin(g1,g2,dist)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) use because the `dist=0` say "no distance" (!). It is `ST_Intersection`?  test your query with a relevant `dist` parameter. About permission: say to your boss that you need permission to get performance (!!).

Comment: About "I think that Postgres will use the index (...) latitude and longitude", you is wrong: or abandon PostGIS or use PostGIS.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

The spatial index of PostGIS is the BBOX.

You is using BBOX when use the `&&`  operator, try first the performance of

```
   SELECT id FROM t
   WHERE 'POLYGON(({points}))' &&  ST_Point(latitude, longitude);
```

The `ST_DWithin` have good performance, but the parameter `0`  says "intersection", so there are no BBOX optimization.

Other problem is cache, because you is build geometries: try

```
   CREATE TABLE kx_t AS 
     SELECT id, 
            'POLYGON(({points}))' as poly, 
            ST_Point(latitude, longitude) as pt  
     FROM t;
```

and test your queries with `kx_t`, so

```
   SELECT id FROM kx_t
   WHERE poly &&  pt;
```

or `WHERE ST_Intersects(poly,pt)`...

With [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) or this `kx_t`  you can use something as  `CREATE INDEX xxx ON kx_t USING GIST (the_geom)` to enhance performance.

---

PS: copy your question into [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) if no good solution here.

Comment: Thanks, I think that Postgres will use the index if we add something like: `where ... and latitude <= ... and longitude <= ...`, how can we do this?

Comment: Hi @ipetr, post another question. Please, check my answer about your question: vote and accept if here is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I forse Postgres to use index like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM t, ( SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(({points}))') as geom ) as polygon
WHERE longitude >= ST_XMIN(polygon.geom)
AND   longitude <= ST_XMAX(polygon.geom)
AND   latitude >= ST_YMIN(polygon.geom)
AND   latitude <= ST_YMAX(polygon.geom)
AND   ST_DWithin(polygon.geom, ST_Point(latitude, longitude), 0);
```